# JavaScript: загрузка изображений по событию onBlur

Tags: javascript

Есть хтмл форма с полем ввода. В этом поле адрес картинки. Надо чтобы после измения текста в поле, подгружалась уже новая картинка по заданому адресу.
По событию onBlur вызываю функцию, которая должна изменить адрес изображения

```
<img src='image1.gif' name='pic1'>
<input type='text' name='img1' id='img1' value='image1.gif' onblur='iload(1)'>
```

JS-функция:

```
function iload(num)
 {
 pic='pic'+num;
 img='img'+num;
 document.pic.src = document.getElementById(img).value;
 }
```

в хтмл-коде везде индекс "1", т.к. не известно сколько таких элементов будет:1, 2 или 100, поэтому надо универсальное решение.
**Скрипт не работает** и консоль ошибок возвращает следующее:

> [14.02.1971 17:06:45] JavaScript -
> http://site.ru/page.php Event thread:
> blur Uncaught exception: TypeError:
> Cannot convert 'document.pic' to
> object Error thrown at line 6, column
> 1 in iload(num) in
> http://site.ru/script.js:
>     document.pic.src = document.getElementById(img).value;
> called from line 1, column 0 in
> <anonymous function>(event) in
> http://site.ru/page.php:
>     iload(1)

Насколько я сам понимаю, он конвертирует объект "document.pic", а надо "document.pic1" (pic='pic1').

Подскажите что-где изменить, что скрипт заработал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У тега `<img>` нет аттрибута **name**(стандартного) ([htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/html/img))

Поэтому попробуйте изменить его на **id**

```
<img src='image1.gif' id='pic1'>
function iload(num)
{
 pic='pic'+num;
 img='img'+num;
 document.getElementById(pic).src = document.getElementById(img).value;
 }
```

Comment: заработало

Answer (score 1):

Берите элемент по ID.

```
 document.getElementById('img1').attributes['src'].nodeValue = 'newValue';
 //или, если так, как в вашем примере, только правильно:
 document[pic].src = document.getElementById(img).value;
```

Но как-то ваша логика совсем уж страшная.

Comment: в яндексе нашел (: